# Swift - Smart way to cycle through an Array of Array [[Int]]

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I use an Array of Array [[Int]] storing coordinates in a map.
I for example want to replace all "2" with "1".
For this I created 2 for loops which define the array space and check for the content.
This is not very flexible and only works with arrays of the defined size.

```
private func remove2fromArray(currentArray: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {

    var newArray : [[Int]] = currentArray

    for section in 0...14 {
        for row in 0...19 {
            if newArray[section][row] == 2
            { newArray[section][row] = 1 }
        }
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Is there a way to just scan through the content of the array to replace the numbers?

e.g.
currentArray.findAndReplace(find:2, replace: 1) or similar, that works with [[Int]]?

Comment: At least remove those hardcoded ranges. Base the loops on the actual sizes of the arrays.

Comment: Why are you using a 2d array to store coordinates? What is the model here? Wouldn’t it be better to have a `Coordinate` struct and just Store a flat array of them?

Comment: An Array is "An ordered, random-access collection." That doesn't sound like a Coordinate to me. You better make a datatype that better fits a Coordinate.

Comment: Well it works perfectly fine, because i can access array[section][row], which defines in my opinion a two dimensional space - coordinates. Do you mean something like: struct {x:Int;y:Int;value:Int} ? - this will be way harder to feed in my opionion.

Comment: And it would help if you could explain how to replace the card coded ranges, because I was not able to use count for an array in an array. But i might be able to do this with the map function below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let result = array.map { subarray in
    subarray.map { integer -> Int in
        if integer == 2 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return integer
        }
    }
}
```

Even shorter:

```
let result = array.map {
    $0.map { integer in
        return integer == 2 ? 1 : integer
    }
}
```

And a one-liner:

```
let result = array.map { $0.map { $0 == 2 ? 1 : $0 } }
```

I'll try to explain what's happening here in simple words: What map does is that it goes through the array elements one by one and applies a function on the element.

In our example, the first map iterates over the outer array elements, so `$0` here refers to the inner arrays (one after one).

The second map iterates over the inner arrays' elements. So `$0` in the inner map refers to the each element of the inner arrays' elements.

Comment: works like a charm. I guess I will have to read through the manual, what .map actually does, or could you explain the individual parameters?
map returns an array, which individual content is represented by the $0 and modified by the functions after. where can I learn about the short functions with "?" and ":"? This seems so lean.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain what's going on. If you need more explanation please let me know.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!